# How can I invert colors on ONE screen in Mac OS X?

Tags: colors, osx-leopard

I know that trick with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd>, but is it possible to invert colors only for one monitor? It's extremely great to program with these colors.. but I need one normal monitor also for preview =(

Comment: have you considered just setting the colours in your IDE to a scheme you like better? What IDE are you using?

Comment: Agree with @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, it seems to me you're using a hacksaw when a scalpel would do.

Comment: no people it's impossible to configure whole eclipse that way, ofcourse i like coda and etc.. but still I want whole screen black. vim,emac or at least coda doesnt' have syntax spell checker, source file indexer which could autocomplete current code not just language classes/functions.. and etc and etc.. anyway inverted colors also great for using some software like CAD apps... 3d apps..

Comment: and btw having that source indexer and spell correction + file browser, and dark themed gui.. I think this really impossible for any IDE on earth for now. imagine XSI or logic studio style gui with eclipse, I would die from pleasure.. maybe the same feelings would be if coda had source indexing..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Michel Fortin's [Black Light](http://michelf.ca/projects/black-light/) does it.

> With Black Light you can apply a combination of visual effects to your screen by manipulating the gamma curve. Opening Black Light will automatically apply the selected effects. Quiting the application will restore the original settings. Clicking on the Black Light icon in the dock will activate and deactivate the selected effect combination.

I even donated to him =]

Comment: How to make it work on one display only?

Comment: well it was working on separate monitors before lion. prolly on maverics should work too

Comment: Thanks but didn't figure out how to do it in Mavericks.

Comment: sorry i don't have second monitor to test now, moved abroad..

Comment: Unfortunately Black Light Invert Colors doesn't work at all for me.  All the other options work perfectly!  Still looking for a solution to invert colors on a secondary monitor using DisplayLink.

Comment: Upgraded to High Sierra and Black Light works now on primary monitor - still does not work with my DisplayLink secondary monitor, unfortunately.

Comment: This works perfectly! I have an e-ink monitor and 2 4k normal monitors, this now allows me to code on the e-ink one on the same computer!

Answer (score 2):

There's also an interesting hardware "solution" that works.

I have a Diamond BVU195 USB display adapter to connect additional monitors.  It uses the DisplayLink technology.  When reversing colors, monitors connected through the USB adapter do not reverse.  I'm assuming it's a to do w/ the DisplayLink drivers, so any adapter that uses [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/) would probably do the same.

Comment: This is unfortunately true - can't use my screens without accessibility features and didn't knew this before...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a SO link to dark colour schemes for Eclipse. You're not the only one. ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120621/dark-color-scheme-for-eclipse

Comment: I knew it could be done. ;-)

Comment: it can be done for editor only, not for the whole gui. infact we managed finally to custom editor very well, because FINALLY somebody posted a config file for pydev. anyway this is just for editor only. other tab background just killing my eyes.. invert colors are da best, and linux have best implementation of this, even for every window! =) and that invert is better, because it's inverting in vectors. anyway try it, it's better..

Comment: I suppose in theory a person could get the source for the windowing toolkit that Eclipse uses, re-write parts to allow for colour-schemes, then recompile Eclipse using the modified windowing toolkit (with some new preferences to configure the colour schemes)...

Comment: maybe SOMEBODY will make this great step after 10 years from now.. ;D